# How do I correct the kernel version loaded by Grub2 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-12.04, grub2

I have a linux vps running Ubuntu 12.04 and when I run `uname-r` it replies:

```
paul@webforms:~$ uname -r
2.6.32.33-kvm-i386-20111128-dirty
paul@webforms:~$ sudo grub-install -v
grub-install (GRUB) 1.99-21ubuntu3.1
```

if I run update-grub I get:

```
paul@webforms:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-15-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-15-generic-pae
done
```

and then rebooting gives me the same dirty kernel

I'm going round in circles and as a relative noob I'm sure I must be missing something obvious so over to the hive-mind!!

Comment: Why do you think you need to update or worry about the kernel?

Comment: rsyslogd is consuming 99% of CPU and so Apache page loads are in the 2000ms range. If I stop rsyslog they are in the range of 600ms. I've seen discussions where updating to a more recent kernel can fix the issue. But also more generally I'm confused as to why the loaded kernel would be one that isn't listed in grub...

Comment: Ah, someone has pointed out that the kernel listed by uname is the KVM kernel and so is due to the virtualisation being used... I've logged a ticket with my host

Answer (score 2):

On the off-chance that some as inexperienced as me gets here via Google... the kernel reported was a KVM kernel which means my VPS is using shared kernel virtualisation (http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_of_Virtualization_Techniques#Shared_Kernel_Virtualization) and so I couldn't update the kernel from within the VPS.

I contacted my host who have a secure console through which I could change the kernel version.

Incidentally this update also fixed the rsyslogd problem mentioned in the comments on the question.